# Newman run collection and envirment from Github repo

Tags: github, postman, teamcity, postman-collection-runner, newman

I have a collection and enviroment .json in github and I would like to run them in TeamCity using the following url:

```
newman run RegressionTestsFT.postman_collection.json -e FT.postman_environment.json --reporters cli,htmlextra --insecure
```

but when I do this I got the following error:

```
error: could not load environment
09:35:19     ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'FT.postman_environment.json'
```

the url of in github is as follow:

```
/postman/blob/master/PostmanRegressionTests/FT.postman_environment.json
/postman/blob/master/PostmanRegressionTests/RegressionTestsFT.postman_collection.json
```

I think the url I am using in the newman command is wrong but I don't know how to build it so it can targit the above url in Github.

I tried to midify the newman code but didn't work

Comment: If you get the `raw` url link from that github file from browser, that could be used in the Newman command. Not the best, ideal or efficient way of running the collection though.

Comment: Thank you Danny , I have done this but now I got this error error: could not load environment
Unexpected token '<' at 1:1 <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: I have also tried another way and got this error: error: collection could not be loaded
  the url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RestOfUrl" did not provide valid JSON data
  Unexpected token ':' at 1:4
404: Not Found

Comment: OK now I managed it be working using the raw url, but as you said this is not the best way to do it.

Comment: If the Collection is in your Postman account, I would recommend using the Postman API URL for the Collection. That would be the most up-to-date version of the Collection.

Comment: my approach is different, I use Teamcity to run those collections after each release.
So the idea is to run these collections in Teamcity from Github repo.

Answer (score 0):

I could manage to do this, by passing the correct url of repo and using the token from the version control seeting in TeamCity.